# "OR" regular expression using eclipse search

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse IDE and im trying to search file by string. Search -> File. Check regular expression checkbox.

Containing text: (appl.acq.std.acptr.re.mng | appl.acq.std.merch.re.mng)

I need to search for the text "appl.acq.std.acptr.re.mng" OR "appl.acq.std.merch.re.mng"

Comment: That's `appl\.acq\.std\.(acptr|merch)\.re\.mng`.

Comment: Dot is a special character in regular expressions so you must escape it if you want it to just match `.` Also spaces are not ignored so don't put spaces around the `|`